# Python - Script for payment degree

Tags: python

I have a set of costumers that should pay a monthly sum. But in reality some of the customers pays zero or only a part of that sum each month. How can I calculate their payment degree for a year using python? And is percent the best way to describe the payment degree, and is "payment degree" the correct word to use at all?

example:

```
customer X should pay 275 each month 
payments = [jan : 200, feb : 0, march: 150, april : 275, may : 275, jun : 20, july : 275, aug : 186, sep : 0, oct : 20, nov : 275, dec : 200 ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by payment degree so I'd be inclined to say there's a better term. Could you give the result you'd expect from your example?

Comment: By payment degree, are you looking for the percent of what they owed they actually paid?  As in, if they owe $275 each month, and paid $200, it would output 73%?

Comment: How is your `payments` structured? Is it a `list` or a `dict`? In any way, just `sum` the values and do some basic arithmetic. What exactly is the question?

Comment: The percentage of what they have payed of the total 275*12month last year - in 2014. This is just an example, I am looking for a python script/code to calculate this for all customers

Comment: it's a dict. I am also wondering about the English term for payment degree?

Comment: So: your customers owe $3300 a year, and you're looking for what percent the customer has paid of that $3300?  It might help if you provided some attempts you've made to solve this yourself.

Comment: You see, that is not the point... the python code is the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
payments = {
    "jan": 200, "feb":   0, "mar": 150, "apr": 275,
    "may": 275, "jun":  20, "jul": 275, "aug": 186,
    "sep":   0, "oct":  20, "nov": 275, "dec": 200
}

MONTHLY = 275

paid = sum(payments.values())
should_be = MONTHLY * len(payments)

pct = (paid / should_be) * 100.0

print("Customer paid {:0.1f}% of their bill".format(pct))
```

results in

```
Customer paid 56.8% of their bill
```

Comment: @R0LL: glad to help, but ekrah has a point too - the point is not "the code", it's learning why the code works and how to do it yourself.

Comment: I see your confusion, I was not asking for the calculation method.. I understand how to do this kind of math on a piece of paper, but I don't know how to do it in Python! I should have explained that part better I see now.. anyways thank you!